# OpenSceneGraph performance between Qt 4.7 and 4.8

Tags: c++, qt, openscenegraph

I'm working with OpenSceneGraph 3.0.1 (the latest stable) and Qt. OSG has a module named osgQt to create a widget for OSG rendering. I have noticed a strange frame rate drop switching from Qt 4.7 to 4.8.
With 4.7.3, the frame rate was maximum 60fps on every computer.
With 4.8 the frame is maximum 38-40fps on every computer. Definitely too much to accept.
I cannot understand why! Is it a bug or what?

Comment: I see there is a duplicate of this post, with several messages following it up, at http://lists.openscenegraph.org/pipermail/osg-users-openscenegraph.org/2012-March/056916.html

Comment: I know, it's me, thanks ;)
But still there is no solution.

Comment: I mentioned it for the benefit of other readers! :-)

Comment: There were several bugs in Qt 4.8.0 related to framerate dropdown. Did you try with Qt 4.8.1 ? [link](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-23253) and [link](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-24602)

Comment: Yep, with 4.8.1 now I'm back to 60fps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Qt 4.8.1 now I'm back to 60fps!